# How to convert .jpg images to .eps?

Tags: images, jpeg, eps, image-conversion

How can I convert a .jpg image to an .eps?

Answer (score 14):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) can do this.

From the commandline, simply type:

```
convert filename.jpg filename.eps
```

(On Windows you may need to put in the full path to `convert.exe` inside quotation marks; the above will work as-is on OS X or linux.)

It doesn't really make any sense to convert a raster graphic to a vector graphic, however. It'll still be rasterized.

---

Another way of doing it with a GUI would be to use [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org); I'm pretty sure it can import most formats, and it definitely can export to .eps — it does have some ways of trying to trace paths in a vector image to recreate the vectors, but it's far from failsafe.

Just be sure to "embed" rather than "link" when you import.

Comment: I ever wrote a small webpage to convert images to EPS for myself: [JPG to EPS converter](http://www.fclose.com/t/jpg2eps/) . This may help others without a Linux aside.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to convert an image or two to eps - use an online utility...

[Convert Image To EPS](http://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-eps)

Comment: Not helpful if you have a large number of files

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the jpeg image contained in the .eps file (and not vectorized), try this code

http://code.google.com/p/sam2p/

It's C++ source, and takes several image formats and puts them inside a compliant .eps file as an embedded image.

Answer (score 0):

if the question involves postscript the answer is generally [ghostscript / ghostview](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/)

Answer (score 0):

I use online converter:

http://www.online-utility.org/image_converter.jsp?outputType=EPS

Answer (score 0):

gimp is a great tool for converting files to other popular formats - http://www.gimp.org

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I know for something that runs locally, is lossless, and performs well is to take the output of [img2pdf](https://gitlab.mister-muffin.de/josch/img2pdf) and feed it to `pdftops` from [Poppler](https://poppler.freedesktop.org/) (`poppler-utils` on Debian-family distros).

`img2pdf` is specifically designed for converting one or more images into a one-image-per-page PDF file in a lossless fashion (ImageMagick and Ghostscript will decode and re-encode JPEGs, which is lossy) and, since both formats are Postscript-based, it shouldn't need to be re-transcoded in the move from PDF to EPS.

The conversion would looks like like:

```sh
img2pdf --out filename.pdf filename.jpg
pdftops -f 1 -l 1 -eps filename.pdf filename.eps
rm filename.pdf
```

The `-f 1` and `-l 1` specify the first and last page to convert, and are both required to be `1` when using `-eps`.